# Negative Gini Coefficiente?

Tags: microeconomics, econometrics

Is it possible to have a negative gini coefficient?
In which situations is it possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr** No, it is not possible to have a negative Gini coefficient.

[The Gini coefficient is the area between the line of equality and the Lorentz curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient), and this area cannot be negative. Let the area of equality as in the link be denoted by $A$, and the area under the Lorentz curve be denoted by $B$, then the Gini coefficient is given by

$$ G = \frac{A-B}{B}$$

If negative income (or whatever you are measuring) is not permitted, the maximum inequality is $1$. If negative income is permitted, it can potentially be larger than $1$. In any case, the minimum for the Gini coefficient is $0$, which corresponds to total equality.

Comment: I don't know why, but I've seen some pictures where the lorentz curve is above the line of equality...